# Trying to create index, but variable cannot reach defined value [Python]

Tags: python, variables, indexing

I am trying to create an index of a .txt file, which has section titles in all caps. My attempt looks like this:

```
dictionary = {}
line_count = 0
for line in file:
    line_count += 1
    line = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]','',line)
    list = []
    if line.isupper():
       head = line
    else:
       list = line.split(' ')
       for i in list:
           if i not in stopwords:
               dictionary.setdefault(i, {}).setdefault(head, []).append(line_count)
```

The `head` variable, however, cannot find its value, which I am trying to assign to any lines that are all caps. My desired output would be something like:

```
>>dictionary['cat']
{'THE PARABLE': [3894, 3924, 3933, 3936, 3939], 'SNOW': [4501], 'THE CHASE': [6765, 6767, 6772, 6773, 6785, 6802, 6807, 6820, 6823, 6839]}
```

Here is a slice of the data:

```
THE GOLDEN BIRD

A certain king had a beautiful garden, and in the garden stood a tree
which bore golden apples. These apples were always counted, and about
the time when they began to grow ripe it was found that every night one
of them was gone. 

THE PARABLE

Influenced by those remarks, the bird next morning refused to bring in
the wood, telling the others that he had been their servant long enough,
and had been a fool into the bargain, and that it was now time to make a
change, and to try some other way of arranging the work. Beg and pray
as the mouse and the sausage might, it was of no use; the bird remained
master of the situation, and the venture had to be made. They therefore
drew lots, and it fell to the sausage to bring in the wood, to the mouse
to cook, and to the bird to fetch the water.
```

Comment: Where's the data?

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Sorry, added, @StephenRauch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the heart your problem is that this:

```
if line.isupper()
```

this test will fail for a number (`'0'`) or other such things.  Instead try:

```
if line.isupper() == line:
```

But in general your code could use a little Pythonic love like maybe:

```
import re
data = {}
head = ''
with open('file1', 'rU') as f:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f):
        line = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]', '', line)
        if line.isupper() == line:
            head = line
        else:
            for word in (w for w in line.split(' ') if w not in stopwords):
                data.setdefault(word, {}).setdefault(head, []).append(line_num+1)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I had not learned the `enumerate` function before, and that was very helpful to implement.